# Efficiently run hash collision checker

Tags: php, hash, crc32, hash-collision

I'm trying to run the ff.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');

$result = [];

$num = 100_000_000_000;
$salt = 'some random salt';


for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++)  
    $result[crc32($salt.$i)] = true;

if (count($result) != $num)
    echo 'Collision'.PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Ok'.PHP_EOL;
```

But I hit the machine's limit and get

`mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory`

`Fatal error: Out of memory`

Is there a way to efficiently do this in terms of memory?

Comment: Why are you using underscores for `100_000_000_000`? Edit: I get an error back when testing.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner For readability, it's valid PHP as of `7.4`

Comment: ah ok. I didn't know that, thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you need to do this in memory rather than on disk?

Comment: @lufc I believe it would take significantly longer

Comment: thinking big numbers like that you might need to use bit shifting sum other then storing it in an array, bit beyond me though ;p

Comment: It would, but you only need to do this once, as the CRC of the numbers 0 through 100bn will not change. Are you assuming that $num will change often?

Comment: @lufc Yeah but we're talking about days aren't we?

Comment: btw crc will collide way before stopping its like on the 36k mark for 0-n

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yeah I forgot to put salt in the example, I updated the code now.

Comment: The estimated memory use of this code is something around 5TB. Just buy more memory :D

Comment: You could try something like storing the first 8 bytes of the checksum instead of the entire thing, and store the integers which mapped into those 8 characters. Then rerun individually wherever you have a collision.

Comment: btw you should also check for collisions on each iteration rather than at the end. At the moment you would use the full 100m memory blocks even if the collision happened on the first block.

Comment: See also: https://medium.com/@rtheunissen/efficient-data-structures-for-php-7-9dda7af674cd

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you don't need to do that in PHP `7.4`